# How to dynamically refer to nodes within tikz environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, arithmetic

Here is my code with two tikzpictures. I was expecting both to produce similar output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle,draw,minimum size=5mm] (r0) at (0, 0) {};
\node[rectangle,draw,minimum size=5mm] (r1) at (10mm, 0) {};
\node[rectangle,draw,minimum size=5mm] (r2) at (20mm, 0) {};
\node[rectangle,draw,minimum size=5mm] (r3) at (30mm, 0) {};
\draw[->] (r0) -- (r1);
\draw[->] (r1) -- (r2);
\draw[->] (r2) -- (r3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{20mm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,...,3}
    \node[rectangle,draw,minimum size=5mm] (r\i) at (10mm * \i, 0) {};
\foreach \i in {0,...,2} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\j}{\i + 1}
    \draw[->] (r\i) -- (r\j);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output.

[image]

Why are the arrows in the second tikzpicture environment piercing into the boxes? What makes the code in the second tikzpicture environment different from the first one?

Comment: You need `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\j}{\i + 1}` and this question is a duplicate, I only need to find it.

Comment: Don't you get an error?

Comment: @cfr The only suspicious thing I get in the output while running pdflatex is `ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros`. Don't know if this is trying to tell me that there has been an error.

Comment: @LoneLearner That is just a message from the `everyshi` package which is loaded by TikZ to be able to draw on the page background.  Nothing to be worried about.

Comment: Never mind me. You won't get an error because the decimal part of the values will be treated as a node anchor very close to 0 i.e. east.